# Function for replacing value in column data

Tags: python-3.x

I have 110 variables and I want to replace value as follows:

```
def out_treat(x):
    miss_treat[x] = np.where(miss_treat[x]< miss_treat[x].min(),miss_treat[x].min(),miss_treat[x])
    miss_treat[x] = np.where(miss_treat[x]> np.percentile(miss_treat[x],95),np.percentile(miss_treat[x],95),miss_treat[x])
    return miss_treat

for t in x:
    print(t)
    print(out_treat(t))
```

The above code is giving me actual data without any change

```
np.where(miss_treat['Int Expenses to Tot Deposits']< miss_treat['Int Expenses to Tot Deposits'].min(),miss_treat['Int Expenses to Tot Deposits'].min(),miss_treat['Int Expenses to Tot Deposits'])
```

When I tried the above code it's working well but when I transform the same in function, it give me the same data as orginal.

please tell what is the best way to write a proper function?

Comment: Is `miss_treat` a pandas dataframe?

Comment: it's a data from excel file

Comment: how did you import the excel file into python?

Comment: data = pd.read_excel(file path)

Comment: I think your code will modify the original data, assuming `miss_treat = pd.read_excel(file_path)` was what you had

Comment: Ya actually its working now. I fixed it just want to know one thing how can I put the result in one dataframe like when I run this for loop, the result should save in outlier_data

Comment: All done. thanks for your support